# json_decode () breaking when called directly in the Laravel Blade template - (expects string, object given)

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-8, htmlspecialchars

I have a Laravel `Results` model that returns some data from a database to a blade view from a 'results' table. 
One of the columns is called `properties` which is of a `json` datatype and it stores data similar to the following:

```
{
"clubs": [
    {
        "id": 1741008,
        "name": "BanterburyFC",
        "wins": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": 17844730,
        "name": "es ticazzi",
        "wins": "1"
    }
]
}
```

The index controller gets the results from the `getResults()` function which returns an array of values such as `match_id, home_team_goals, away_team_goals & properties` - the properties (which is of a json datatype in the MySQL database is looped through on the frontend & I do the json_decode directly in the blade template, however it gives me the following error.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /Users/myname/Projects/myapp/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)
```

Weirdly when I run the `json_decode()` on the same data in the controller before I pass this into the view it works fine and creates an object as expected. However for some reason when I attempt to run the `json_decode` directly inside the blade view it returns the Error Exception above.

What's wrong?

Controller logic

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $data = [ 'results' => Result::getResults($user->properties) ];

    // var_dumping so I can check the data before it is passed to the blade view
    var_dump($data['results'][0]->properties);  // returns string - looks fine & this doesn't return any errors
    var_dump(json_decode($data['results'][0]->properties)); // returns object - looks fine & this doesn't return any errors either
    return view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

Blade view/template

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    {{ json_decode($result->properties) }} <!-- the line causing the problem -->
    {{ json_decode($result->properties, true) }} <!-- this also fails -->
@endforeach
```

Using PHP 8.x & Laravel 8.x

Comment: The error is pretty clear, `expects string, object given`, it is already an object, no need to `json_decode` that variable... Also, don't use `json_decode`, stop using vanilla PHP. Laravel can [take care of this automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Laravel blade `{{}}` is equal to `echo` so it accept string not an object. It uses `htmlspecialchars` internally for XSS protection against injection. So when you are trying to do `{{ json_decode($result->properties) }}`, it is throughing the error. Instead you can use `@php ... @endphp` directives.

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    @php $p = json_decode($result->properties); @endphp 
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you Sharma.. that was really doing my head in :)

Comment: You can take a look at Blade doc for more details. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade